# Direction of steering torque while cornering in a bike

Tags: rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

While steadily cornering with a constant turn radius, is any force required on the handlebar to maintain it steady? In simpler terms, when I leave my hands off the handlebar while in the middle of cornering, does it steer into the corner or away from the corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a bike with no initial lean and an initial steering angle of $\theta$ released with a velocity $v$ on the road. The fate of the bike depends on whether $v$ is greater or lesser than these 3 speeds of interest.

a. Double root speed: Below this speed, the bike simply falls like an inverted pendulum. Above this speed and below the weave speed, oscillations begin and increase in amplitude with time until the bike eventually falls over. With increasing speed, the number of times the bike oscillates until it falls over increases.

b. Weave speed: Above this speed and below the capsize speed, oscillations decrease in amplitude with time and eventually die out. With increasing speed, the number of oscillations the bike makes until it is stable decreases. Also, the lean angle at which the bike becomes stable increases with speed (from $0$ to certain constant $\alpha$).

c. Capsize speed: Above this speed, there is no lean angle of stability, i.e., the bike oscillates for a while and eventually falls over. Both the amplitude and number of oscillations that occur before falling over decrease with speed.

Between these last two speeds, the particular bike design is self-stable for specific lean angles (i.e. requires no steering input).

[image]

For the above figure, the double root speed is $1$ $m/s$, weave speed is $5.3$ $m/s$, and capsize speed is $8$ $m/s$.

To answer your question, once a turn is established in a bike, the torque required on the handlebar in order to maintain a constant radius at a constant speed for a constant lean angle depends on the forward speed of the bike. During a turn, the gyroscopic effects of the front wheel as well as the torque produced by the normal force on it will tend to steer the handlebar-front wheel assembly into the turn; whereas, the torque produced by the centripetal force will tend to steer it out of the turn. Which effect is dominant depends on the speed of the bike and the radius of the turn. For a constant radius of turn, below the capsize speed, the handle bar would tend to steer into the corner, whereas above the capsize speed, it would tend to steer out of the corner.

Note, this is also related to why one needs to apply greater force on the handlebar to counter steer at higher speeds, as greater is the speed of the bike, greater would be the torque due to centripetal force on the front wheel acting opposite to our steering torque. Also note, this centripetal force generated torque together with the gyroscopic precession of the rotating front wheel produced while turning the handlebar are what cause the bike to lean during counter steering.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation, in circus they do this all the time, riding in a circle without touching the handlebar. I am not saying there is no force acting, maybe they just balance it out. Interesting question, but probably not so easy to proof.